# How do I create a simple HUD, with ImageButton and background, using LibGDX?

Tags: java, libgdx

Here is my HUD class:

```
public class UpperPanelHUD extends Table {

    private final TextureRegion textureRegion;
    private ItemButton itemButton;
    private Maze maze;

    public UpperPanelHUD(Maze maze) {
        this.setBounds(0,  RandoMaze.MAZE_HEIGHT+2, RandoMaze.MAZE_WIDTH, 2);
        this.maze = maze;
        this.textureRegion = Assets.gameAtlas.findRegion("Panel_Up");
        this.itemButton = new ItemButton();
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
        super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);
        itemButton.draw(batch, parentAlpha);
        batch.draw(this.textureRegion, this.getX(), this.getY(), 11, 2);
    }
}
```

and here is my `ItemButton`:

```
public class ItemButton extends ImageButton {

    private TextureRegionDrawable textureRegionDrawable
            = new TextureRegionDrawable(Assets.gameAtlas.findRegion("Key"));

    public ItemButton() {
        super(new  TextureRegionDrawable(Assets.gameAtlas.findRegion("Key")));
        this.setBounds(0, 0, 1, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
        super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);
        batch.draw(this.textureRegionDrawable.getRegion(), this.getX(), this.getY(), 1, 1);
    }
}
```

`itemButton` is drawn without relation to its parent `UpperPanelHUD`, and I need it be positioned inside `UpperPanelHUD`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I solved the problem:

```
   public UpperPanelHUD(Maze maze) {

    this.setBounds(0,  RandoMaze.MAZE_HEIGHT+2, RandoMaze.MAZE_WIDTH, 2);
    this.maze = maze;
    this.textureRegionDrawable=new TextureRegionDrawable (Assets.gameAtlas.findRegion("Panel_Up"));
    this.setBackground(textureRegionDrawable);
    this.itemButton = new ItemButton();

    this.addActor(this.itemButton);
}...
```

And for my ItemButton:

```
public class ItemButton extends ImageButton {
    public ItemButton() {
        super(new TextureRegionDrawable (Assets.gameAtlas.findRegion("Key")));
        this.setBounds(1, 0.5f, 1, 1);
    }
}
```